# What is this Ethernet connector (from a 1999 Sony Vaio) called?

Tags: ethernet, adapter, sony-vaio

My Sony Vaio PCG-Z505S has a strange, flat Ethernet connector that looks like this:

[image]

The laptop came with an adapter to connect a normal "RJ45" network cable to it, but I have lost it. Now I'm wondering if anyone knows (or is smart enough to google) the name of the connector so that I might be able to find another such adapter to buy.

Comment: These types of connectors were (to the best of my knowledge) never standardized, so it might not have a name.  You might be able to call Sony and get a part number for the dongle, though.  That combined with Google should get you a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Sony to determine the correct part number for your Model, then use Google to locate a used or new old stock one.
http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/model-accessories.pl?mdl=PCGZ505S

https://servicesales.sel.sony.com/ecom/accessories/web/productSearch.do?searchOperation=modelSearch&sessionId=SpWwro72hLFMN-b7AdFxmQN&modelNum=PCGZ505S&searchText=PCGZ505S

Might be cheaper to buy a usb ethernet adapter.
http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=usb+ethernet+adapter&x=0&y=0

Comment: Thanks, contacting Sony worked it out: it's a part n:o 195986911, "HARNESS, RJ45", and available for $76.15. Since the value of the laptop itself is likely not much higher than that, with a practically dead battery, I'm gonna think about the purchase for a while.. I'll try a cheap USB adapter first, though the OS being Windows 98 (not SE, but the plain old one) makes things complicated with almost all things USB.

Comment: You might be able to find a W98SE upgrade disc on eBay for cheap. You would think Sony would greatly reduce the price of that cable just to get it out of inventory.